# How to dual boot Ubuntu without USB in Windows PC

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, bootloader, 23.04

This is a weird setup, I know, but I tried to dual boot Ubuntu 23.04 without USB in my Windows PC. Fr that, I added the ISO file to separate F:\ drive which is fat32 and edited the bootloader using bcdedit . I created a 80 GB partition on E:\ drive, so I thought I could install Ubuntu to E:, but when I restarted and tried to load from that entry it showed an error like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbmW4.jpg).

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."
    
If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \EFI\boot\bootx64.efi
    
  Status: 0xc000007b
```

my bcdedit entry for boot live Ubuntu from F:\ is :

```
Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {3ff08e90-6caa-11ee-9f36-c475ab038c1f}
device                  partition=F:
path                    \EFI\boot\bootx64.efi
description             Ubuntu Live installation media
```

Why doesn't it boot? Is it due to the wrong path?
Help me to boot the live USB from Windows Boot Manager.

I have only one SSD which has C:, D:, E: and F:

Comment: you could try EasyBCD